# addEventListener Click not working multiple times just once

Tags: javascript, events, click, dom-events, addeventlistener

I want to increase `cart.amount` on any event click but has work one time
should be a refresh to increase another one:

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < amount_btns_up.length; i++) {
    amount_btns_up[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      id = e.target.dataset.amount;
      amount_change_up(id);
    });
  }
});

function amount_change_up(id) {
  mycart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myCart"));
  for (let j = 0; j < mycart.length; j++) {
    if (mycart[j].ISBN === id) {
      mycart[j].amount++;
      
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After incrementing the amount of the item, you'll need to save it back to Local Storage for the line

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myCart"))
```

to parse the updated amount on subsequent clicks.

```
function amount_change_up(id) {
  mycart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myCart"));
  for (let j = 0; j < mycart.length; j++) {
    if (mycart[j].ISBN === id) {
      mycart[j].amount++;
    }
  }
  localStorage.myCart = JSON.stringify(mycart);
}
```

You also might consider using the more semantically appropriate `.find` method.

```
function amount_change_up(id) {
  mycart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myCart"));
  mycart.find(item => item.ISBN === id).amount++;
  localStorage.myCart = JSON.stringify(mycart);
}
```

Also, unless the `mycart` identifier is used elsewhere in your script, consider making it a local variable instead of a global one. Same for the ID.

```
function amount_change_up(id) {
  const mycart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myCart"));
  mycart.find(item => item.ISBN === id).amount++;
  localStorage.myCart = JSON.stringify(mycart);
}
```

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < amount_btns_up.length; i++) {
    amount_btns_up[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      amount_change_up(e.target.dataset.amount);
    });
  }
});
```

I'd also recommend using `DOMContentLoaded` instead of `load` so that the client doesn't have to wait for images to be fully downloaded for your JS to start working. Or, even better, use an external script with the `defer` attribute on the tag.